# Adding RevitAPI.dll into a Visual Studio

Tags: python, dll, shared-libraries, revit-api

When I'm adding a RevitAPI.dll file into  Visual Studio this message has appeared (The selected component could not be browsed) anyone could support me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you manually navigated to the directory containing Revit.exe and selected the Revit API .NET assembly there?

Have you set the correct version of the .NET framework?

[Revit 2021 requires .NET 4.8](https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2021/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Introduction_Getting_Started_html).

If both answers are yes, your system may be corrupted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed .NET 4.8 it works now

Answer (score 0):

A great way of quickly referencing the Revit API dll files is a nuget package by Matthew Taylor.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Revit_All_Main_Versions_API_x64/

Just select the version required. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB7zL.png)